# QGIS: processing-modeler to add multiple layer name to attribute field

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, formula, qgis-modeler

I'm trying to add layer name using the field-calculator in QGIS (3.4.1). If I do this manualy it works fine, but if I do this using the processing-modeler I get NULL for every field. I just type `@layer_name` in the Formula field. Field-type is string and length is 50. [image]

Comment: Perhaps a bug in 3.4.1? This seems to work fine in 3.4.0.